# How to include the qtsql module?

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

I am new to Qt and C++ (coming from the PHP world) and am stuck on something that is probably pretty obvious: including non-core Qt modules.

I (understandably) get the compile error that `QSqlDatabase does not name a type`.

I also get errors when I include either of the following:

- `#include <QSqlDatabase>`
- `#include <QSql>`

Any idea how to include the QSql module? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
QT += sql
```

To your .pro file to enable this module.

Be careful that you don't do

```
QT = ..
```

after the

```
QT += sql
```

Or simply put all the modules in one line:

```
QT = core gui sql
```

Comment: Thanks. I found a lot of tutorials, but oddly none of them included that critical step. Worked like a charm.